# How can I use hexfloat

Tags: gcc, c++11

Win 7
gcc 4.8.2 (cygwin)

Ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hexfloat/

(and other ref's).

```
stringstream pretty;
pretty << std::hexfloat;
```

Generates a compiler error (‘hexfloat’ is not a member of ‘std’) with -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11. So, despite its simplicity, how do I use it?

I've tried as many variants as I can think of. At this point I've just gotta' ask if gcc is standards compliant.

I can generate a hexfloat in the printf() functions but not in streams.

Comment: Are you including `<ios>`?

Comment: Yes I am. And I reverified that sprintf() output hexfloat ("%a")

Comment: _&*&Y&$$:KL:J&^$ thanks )(*&&%^$

Answer (score 3):

The G++ development team does list this as missing in the [online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#manual.intro.status.iso) (table 1.5, section 8.10.2), and there is an open bug report for it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59987).

Comment: Read above comment. Sigh. Don't get old. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: But the output option "la" is supported. So a routine like:

Comment: (Sorry). like: string SlipDoubleOp::write(double X) const {
      char buffer[25];
      sprintf(buffer, "%la", *));
      return string(buffer);
//      return toString(X);
   }; // string SlipDoubleOp::write(const SlipCell& X) const

should work. The input can be treated (in similar manner).